# How to avoid Greek letter symbols in lstlisting

Tags: listings, matlab

I am using the `lstlisting` package, but I don't want it to show Greek letters by its symbol.

For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Parameter.delta_x = 0.002e-6;
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want that line `Parameter.delta_x = 0.002e-6;` to appear in that way, showing the  text 'delta', but not the Greek symbol `\delta`.

How can I do what I want?

---

**Edit**: I have found out the reason. As this code was MATLAB code I had typed in the preamble:

`\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}`

The last option, `useliterate`, was obvioulsy incorrect for my necessities.

Comment: I don't see any reason why a delta symbol should appear in this snippet. Make a complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See the EDIT. It was my fault.

Comment: @baister Always post a full compilable example to reproduce your code. It means you have to make a little work to remove al the unnecessary packages for the example, but we won't have to guess. In fact, many times you will find the solution yourself just by creating this minimal compilable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

Ditch `mcode` and use the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package instead `:p`

---

### Detailed answer

You're loading the `mcode` package with its `useliterate` option, which defines, among others, a literate replacement for `delta`:

```
literate=%
  %...
  {delta}{{\tiny$\Delta$}}1 %    \Delta
  %...
```

The `mcode` package actually defines many other literate replacements (such as `<=` by `≤`); some of them are used as a rudimentary way of highlighting MATLAB's `end` keyword differently, depending on whether it means "last element of an array", as in

```
x(2:end)
```

or whether it closes a block (loop, if statement, etc.), as in

```
for i=1:10
  %...
end
```

You may find some of those literate replacements undesirable (as I do), but `mcode` doesn't provide an easy way to disable them without also breaking the mechanisms put in place for highlighting the `end` keyword.

You have two options, here:

#### 1 - Stick with `mcode` but get rid of undesirable literate replacement(s)

This approach is a pain in the neck, but that's what you have to do if you insist on using `mcode`. In your preamble, after loading the `mcode` package with options,

```
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
```

add the following lines:

```
\makeatletter
\ifmcode@useliterate
  \lstset{%
    literate=%
      {~}{{$\neg$}}1 % 
      {<=}{{\tiny$\leq$}}1 %
      {>=}{{\tiny$\geq$}}1 %
      {~=}{{\tiny$\neq$}}1 %
      %{delta}{{\tiny$\Delta$}}1 % comment this one out
      {µ}{{$\mu$}}1 %
      {(end)}{\lstbasicfont (end)}{5}
      {({ }end)}{\lstbasicfont ({ }end)}{6}
      {(end{ })}{\lstbasicfont (end{ })}{6}
      {({ }end{ })}{\lstbasicfont ({ }end{ })}{7}
      {:end}{\lstbasicfont :end}{4}
      {:{ }end}{\lstbasicfont :{ }end}{5}
      {end:}{\lstbasicfont end:}{4}
      {end{ }:}{\lstbasicfont end{ }:}{5}
      {,end}{\lstbasicfont ,end}{4}
      {,{ }end}{\lstbasicfont ,{ }end}{5}
  }
\else
  \lstset{%
    literate=%
      {(end)}{\lstbasicfont (end)}{5} %
      {({ }end)}{\lstbasicfont ({ }end)}{6}
      {(end{ })}{\lstbasicfont (end{ })}{6}
      {({ }end{ })}{\lstbasicfont ({ }end{ })}{7}
      {:end}{\lstbasicfont :end}{4}
      {:{ }end}{\lstbasicfont :{ }end}{5}
      {end:}{\lstbasicfont end:}{4}
      {end{ }:}{\lstbasicfont end{ }:}{5}
      {,end}{\lstbasicfont ,end}{4}
      {,{ }end}{\lstbasicfont ,{ }end}{5}
      {µ}{$\mu$}1
      {~}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\texttildelow}}1 %
  }
\fi
\makeatother
```

#### 2 - Ditch `mcode` and use the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package instead

Don't load `mcode` at all; just add the following to your preamble.

```
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  style      = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle = \fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize, % if you want to use Courier
}
```

[`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) doesn't force any such literate replacements on users, and, although I'm biased, it arguably does a better job at highlighting MATLAB code than `mcode` does; see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document/158816#158816), for instance.